Batch update a column from a Select in AS/400
I am trying to use this update statement in order to fill a column Name in a table called MD001 from a table called Patient
MD001(MRN, Name, Address)
Patient(CaseNo, FName, MName, LName,...)
UPDATE QS36F.MD001 m 
SET NAME = 
        (
        SELECT FName || ' ' || Mname || ' ' || LName
        FROM QS36F.PATIENT
        WHERE fname <> '' AND mname <> '' AND lname <> ''
        )
        where  m.MRN  = (SELECT caseno FROM qs36f.patient WHERE caseno = m.MRN) 

I keep getting Result of SELECT more than one row. yet in both tables MRN and CaseNo are primary keys.

The first subquery needs those conditions too.

Your sub-select returns all the rows that have a non-blank name.
Try this:
UPDATE QS36F.MD001 m 
SET NAME = (
    SELECT FName || ' ' || Mname || ' ' || LName
    FROM QS36F.PATIENT
    WHERE caseno = m.MRN
)
WHERE  m.MRN IN (
    SELECT caseno 
    FROM qs36f.patient 
    WHERE fname <> '' AND mname <> '' AND lname <> ''
) 

I basically switched the where clauses. The outer where clause selects all the patients that you want to update, and the inner where clause joins specific records for update.

Not sure what your trying to do but get the select statement to work first.
select name,   
            (
            SELECT FName || ' ' || Mname || ' ' || LName
            FROM QS36F.PATIENT
            WHERE fname <> '' AND mname <> '' AND lname <> ''
            and caseno = m.MRN
            )
    from QS36F.MD001 m
    where name <>
            (
            SELECT FName || ' ' || Mname || ' ' || LName
            FROM QS36F.PATIENT
            WHERE fname <> '' AND mname <> '' AND lname <> ''
            and caseno = m.MRN
            )

Then make an update statement
    update QS36F.MD001 m
set name =   
            (
            SELECT FName || ' ' || Mname || ' ' || LName
            FROM QS36F.PATIENT
            WHERE fname <> '' AND mname <> '' AND lname <> ''
            and caseno = m.MRN
            )
    where name <>
            (
            SELECT FName || ' ' || Mname || ' ' || LName
            FROM QS36F.PATIENT
            WHERE fname <> '' AND mname <> '' AND lname <> ''
            and caseno = m.MRN
            )

And you probably need a few trims in there.

Since you got two different answers here, you can also use the CTE. With is the inside select statement in DB2. You can achieve only with single statement.
I just changed a few things in your code.
with U as (
select count (1) as dummy from new table(  
update MD001 m 
SET NAME = (
        SELECT FName || ' ' || Mname || ' ' || LName
        FROM PATIENT
        WHERE fname <> '' AND mname <> '' AND lname <> ''
        )
  where m.MRN  = (SELECT caseno FROM patient WHERE caseno = m.MRN)
  ))
select * from MD001


dbfiddle

SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0199] Keyword UPDATE not expected. Valid tokens: INSERT.

Reason for the error is: You are using different product than Db2. Please get the logical answer here.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232659/db2-select-from-final-table-update-gives-sql0199-error#:~:text=%5B42601%5D%5B%2D199%5D%20%5BSQL0199%5D%20Keyword%20UPDATE%20not%20expected.%20Valid%20tokens%3A%20INSERT.

I asked around and none answered but I am sure that they are not using DB2 or Windows and since they call it As/400, I think it is db2 for i.

@user10191234 Can you please run this code?
https://dbfiddle.uk/L1HaGptl
I have changed last where condition. Let me know whether it fulfill your requirement.

@user10191234 Yes, DB2 for i. The fiddle lists DB2 for LUW as DB2, but it is not the same. DB2 for i does not support that syntax with UPDATE, only INSERT.
